# Add support for .gifv format in chat onebox

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

Recently [Imgur announced](http://imgur.com/blog/2014/10/09/introducing-gifv/) to drop the legacy GIF format with the new GIFV format.

Why GIFV?

1. It's lightweight
2. Being a video format, it also allows more flexibility like not autoplaying or autoloading by default which `.gif` just disrespects. Oh, and you can pause it too.
3. It supports streaming and loads much much faster than `.gif` to start with.

GIFV is a mutated `.mp4`. As GIF's are already oneboxed in the chat, we should onebox `.gifv` as well.

EDIT :

GifV falls back to webm if .mp4 is not supported

Comment: FFS, people; if you can't discuss the display of animations without it devolving into name-calling, there's no hope. Way to taint the idea. If anyone has any *legitimate arguments* for or against this, post 'em in an answer.

Comment: Some people can't even internet :(

Comment: @Shog9 thanks. I apologize for calling him a troll but he never read imgurs original post... reminded me of folks on stackoverflow

Comment: Put it in your question, @Abhishek - no reason to bother engaging in comments if you can clarify in the post itself.

Comment: What's the browser support for gifv? I've never heard of  that format before.

Comment: @JanDvorak gifv is a fancy way of rendering muted mp4 videos. Read the Imgur announcement, it's all there.

Comment: Can we stop calling it *GIFV* though? They are videos, so just embed MP4s in chat, with muted audio and looping by default.

Comment: @poke sure, but GFIV is still shorter to type out than, "muted, looped MP4" lol

Comment: If you're going to support the oneboxing of animated gifs/videos then there really ought to be a way of stopping them.

Comment: @ChrisF to be fair, current gifs are "unstoppable" for lack of better words, and they're already supported.

Comment: @SterlingArcher - then I'd be happy for current gifs to become unsupported ;)

Comment: Well that's a shame, I disagree of course, but to each their own.

Comment: GifV @ChrisF allows extreme extensibility cause its literally a video :-)

Comment: @Abhishek - you're missing my point. I'd rather that there was no oneboxing of animated anythings in chat. If I want moving pictures I'll go to YouTube.

Comment: @ChrisF post your thoughts in an answer. I also would like to disable oneboxing when needed. This last year in chat I have seen a *few* giant oneboxed phallus, a topless creature bearing both mammaries *and* a phallus and had to explain quite a few scantily clad women to my boss and co-workers.

Comment: What's the status of this request? It doesn't appear an official reaction has been provided.

Answer (score 48):

I think this is a good idea.

No, these are not videos. They are gifs in a smaller format. Gifs auto-play, these are just gifs that are higher quality and slightly longer. There are no ads, no sound, and it's becoming very popular on imgur and will most likely, render the .gif format obsolete.

I think we should stick with the times and allow this feature in.

Despite the "technological" arguments, there is virtually no difference between this and a gif besides quality (ergo filesize), length, and the potential ability to prohibit auto-play and even a pause feature.

I would welcome that.

Comment: Would be extremely helpful for the Game Development chat. We currently have to upload extremely large gif files to show what we are working on. This would allow us to share higher quality and smaller file size files.

Comment: It would be wonderful to stop having tabs crash when we overload them with large gifs. I fully support this, would love to see it.