# Can we make oneboxing optional on mobile chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web, onebox

As the title says. It'd be nice to have oneboxing optional on mobile chat, especially if it were something like click/tap-to-reveal.

Why? Well... my data plan is crying at the tens-of-MB GIFs that get posted now and then.

Related:

- [Add support for .gifv format in chat onebox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242358/add-support-for-gifv-format-in-chat-onebox)

  One of the recent(-ish) changes imgur made is allowing far larger GIFs now. 200 MB is the current limit.
- [Overrides/preferences for chat oneboxing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138314/overrides-preferences-for-chat-oneboxing)

  Very closely related, but I feel this is far more significant for mobile users with low data limits, and therefore worthy of a separate feature request. It doesn't even have to be a preference - oneboxing could just be disabled entirely on the mobile site (though of course I'd prefer the option).

This has security implications because an attacker can post an image of arbitrary size on any server with sufficient storage and bandwidth and link to it on chat. Because chat automatically loads direct image links from any source, one could, with relative ease, post multi-GB animated GIFs and quickly exhaust user data allowances, effectively denying service to chat users.

Comment: Actually, it would be better to just not onebox things that are too big (Slack does this). A few days ago people were oneboxing tons of GIFs in PPCG chat and it absolutely killed my browser. :/

Comment: Sorry about your datas :(

Comment: Some of us are also using laptops with a tethered mobile connection :/ So it would nice if was configurable for normal chat as well.

Comment: Second that - give us the option to chose if we really want to see images from any source other user may decide to link, or if we are really interested in having onebox for amazon items and such. I want to be able to disable it.

Comment: Edited to add information on security implications. It's readily apparent if you look at it from the standpoint of an attacker. It's not an urgent concern, but it would be great if this was addressed soon.

Comment: The security concerns (denial of service) are made mildly more pressing by [how chat reputation is calculated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253487/295684).

Comment: @BenN while true, a troll who would abuse this to post tons of animations would just be chat banned. Actually any user who will abuse onebox will be chat banned, so it's really not that big of a problem. The offending messages can easily be moved to some "trash" room by any room owner.

Comment: @bwDraco see my above comment.